# QGIS crashes when using dxf to shp converter

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I use a GPS to capture data in .dxf, manipulate it in a CAD program that I know how to use, then the dxf2shp converter (I think Python is mentioned) to let me generate .shp files for the end user. Every time I've done this recently, I've got a meesage from QGIS that it has stopped working and will close.  I've tried re-installing QGIS (1.8.0), but still have the same message.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try loading the dxf into QGIS with `Add vector layer`, and then rightclick on the layer and `Save As ...` into shapefile format.

That way you might get better error messages, and a visual control on the data.

For the shapefile, you must decide what coordinate refrenece system you are using (lat/long degrees or metres).

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing that you may have a problem with your processor speed.  I have had issues in the past with this.

In the past, i have added dxf, typically of plans etc., to the viewer.  However i have found it more useful to use the tool in Vector - Data Management Tool - Split Vector Layer. This allows you to split your dxf layer by its internal layers into individual shapefiles for each internal layer.

this should solve your problem.